# [bsoncxx ]How to append a bsoncxx::document::element TO bsoncxx::builder::basic::document?

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I am getting error when try to append a element to a document.

```
bsoncxx::document::value _obj;  //This is Declaration of _obj in diffrent file

bsoncxx::document::element element = _obj.view()[sFieldName];
if (element.length() && element.type() == bsoncxx::type::k_document)
{
    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document bsonBuilder;
    bsonBuilder.append(element); //Getting Error
}
```

> Error: Error  C2664 'void bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::basic::sub_document::append_(bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::concatenate_doc)':
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::document::element'
>   to 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::concatenate_doc'

Please help me to solve this issue, how to convert a element to document or append a element to document.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To append an element to a builder, you'll need to use `bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp` and pass in the key and value from the element separately:

```
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;

bsoncxx::document::element elem = ...;
bsoncxx::builder::basic::document builder;
builder.append(kvp(elem.key(), elem.get_value()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to create this JSON structure:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2":
    {   //this is your sub-document...
        "subkey1": "subvalue1",
        "subkey2": "subvalue2"
    }
}
```

If I compare this structure to your code you are missing the `key2`. Try using the helper-function `kvp()` (Key-Value-Pair)..

---

Attached a little example to create a geospatial query using a polygon.

```
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::sub_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::sub_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;

bsoncxx::builder::basic::document doc{};
doc.append(kvp("info.location",[a_polygon](sub_document subdoc) {
    subdoc.append(kvp("$geoWithin", [a_polygon](sub_document subdoc2)
    {
        subdoc2.append(kvp("$geometry", [a_polygon](sub_document subdoc3)
        {
            subdoc3.append(kvp("type","Polygon"));
            subdoc3.append(kvp("coordinates",[a_polygon](sub_array subarray)
            {
                subarray.append([a_polygon](sub_array subarray2)        
                {
                    for (auto point : a_polygon->points())
                    {
                        subarray2.append([point](sub_array coordArray)
                        {
                            coordArray.append(point.longitude(), point.latitude());
                        });
                    }
                });
            }));
        }));        
    }));
}));
```

Query structure:

```
{
   <location field>: {
      $geoWithin: {
         $geometry: {
            type: <"Polygon" or "MultiPolygon"> ,
            coordinates: [ <coordinates> ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Source: [MongoDB Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin)